# Why is col-lg-5 not stacking up in a smaller screen? Not overflowing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[It opens well in the large screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8OuW.png)

[In smaller screens it doesn't stack over the other one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6T7C.png)

I apologize if this is a silly question, I'm new to this and just need it to design a website for pro-bono service.

```css
.for-flex{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;
}
.requirement-main-div{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
margin-top: 40px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="for-flex"> 
<div class="requirement-main-div col-lg-5">
    <h6>• lorem ipsum.<sup>*</sup> </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. <sup>**</sup></h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:10px;"><sup>*</sup> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:10px;"><sup>**</sup> Lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.</p>


</div>
<div class="requirement-main-div col-lg-5">
       <h6>• lorem ipsum.<sup>*</sup> </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. <sup>**</sup></h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<h6>• lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum. </h6>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:10px;"><sup>*</sup> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.</p>
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:10px;"><sup>**</sup> Lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Using Bootstrap? Add the appropriate tag

Comment: Add `flex-column` and `flex-row-lg` classes to your `for-flex` element. The problem is that `display: flex` is `flex-direction: row` by default. So no matter what your inner classes are, the parent will always be `row`. Adding those classes will tell your parent element to display the children in a column direction until `lg` screens, then it will change the direction to `row`: `<div class="for-flex flex-column flex-row-lg">`

Comment: It's taking the `<div class="for-flex flex-column">` but not `flex-row-lg` [chrome inspect](https://imgur.com/a/ZtYqNFB) looks like this. @disinfor

Comment: Corrected using `flex-lg-row` and not `flex-row-lg`. Thank you for your help @disinfor

Comment: Ooops! I forgot that it's the size first. Glad you got it sorted.